# how to delete rows using if statement

Tags: vba, excel

I have a range of 3 columns in my spreadsheet that need to be deleted using if statement.

Basically, if it shows a date in any of those columns, I should maintain them, if not delete. It is important to highlight that I can't delete rows that have a date in one column but don't have in another, if there is a date in any of them, I should maintain the rows.

I tried to write the following code but I am having problems

```
Sub maintain_only_dates()
    Set Rng = Range("b1:D10000")
    If Rng = Format("ddmmyyyy") Then
        Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 7
    Else
        Range("A:A").EntireRow.Delete
    End If
End Sub
```

I would really appreciate your help. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work...

```
Sub MaintainDateRows()

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 10000 To 1 Step -1
        If IsDate(Cells(i, 2).Value) Or IsDate(Cells(i, 3).Value) Or _
           IsDate(Cells(i, 4).Value) Then
            If IsDate(Cells(i, 2).Value) Then Cells(i, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 7
            If IsDate(Cells(i, 3).Value) Then Cells(i, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 7
            If IsDate(Cells(i, 4).Value) Then Cells(i, 4).Interior.ColorIndex = 7
        Else
            Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

---

Update; To try and address speed issues and selecting different sheets I have added some complexity to the code...
The macro will now format a selected range in a sheet (you should hopefully be able to alter it to your needs...)

```
Sub MaintainDateRows()

    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Call KeepDateRowsAndFormat(Columns("C:F"))

End Sub

Function KeepDateRowsAndFormat(SearchArea As Range)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim i, j As Integer
    Dim flag As Boolean
    Dim FirstAddress As String

    On Error Resume Next
    Dim FirstCol As Long: FirstCol = SearchArea.Find("*", LookIn:=xlValues, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Column
    Dim LastCol As Long: LastCol = SearchArea.Find("*", LookIn:=xlValues, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
    Dim FirstRow As Long: FirstRow = SearchArea.Find("*", LookIn:=xlValues, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Row
    Dim LastRow As Long: LastRow = SearchArea.Find("*", LookIn:=xlValues, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    If LastRow = 0 Then Exit Function
    On Error GoTo 0

    Dim RealSearchArea As Range
    Set RealSearchArea = Range(Cells(FirstRow, FirstCol), Cells(LastRow, LastCol))

    ' Format Date Cells
    Application.FindFormat.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
    With RealSearchArea
        .Activate
        Dim Rng As Range
        Set Rng = .Find("*", LookIn:=xlValues, After:=ActiveCell, LookAt:=xlPart, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, SearchFormat:=True)
        If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
            FirstAddress = Rng.Address
            Do
                Rng.Interior.ColorIndex = 7
                Set Rng = .FindNext(Rng)
            Loop While Not Rng Is Nothing And Rng.Address <> FirstAddress
        End If
    End With

    ' Remove Non Date Rows
    For i = LastRow To FirstRow Step -1
        flag = False
        j = FirstCol
        Do
            If IsDate(Cells(i, j).Value) = True Then flag = True
            j = j + 1
        Loop While flag = False And j <= LastCol
        If flag = False Then Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Function
```

Comment: thanks a lot, the macro works but its a bit slow. do you know if there is any way to make it quicker?

Comment: @user7004: If the code works, you should probably accept the answer. I think the slowness *may* be down to the fact that you don't have 10,000 rows. You could try finding the index of the last row in the range and then run the sub on those rows only. You might also try changing "IsDate" for "Format(ddmmyyy)" but that's again down to you.

Comment: One quick way to make the code run a little faster is to turn off Screen refreshing.  As the macro runs, the screen will remain static, until completed.  Just add this as "False" at the beginning, and add as "True" at the end (just before End Sub): `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`

Comment: thank you very much. I would like to do the same process but in another spreadsheet, how can i write this? I tried "With worksheet("sheet2) and then end with but it didnt work